# Why doesn't the JQuery animate() function (for changing the value of height property) work in this SSCCE, while the css() works fine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

In the given (first) SSCCE, I have tried to animate initial 0px height of `.scroll-header` to 70px by `$(".scroll-header").animate({height:"70px"}, 350);` based on a condition (which is when the `.view` is scrolled out of the screen during the window scrolling event - have used the jquery-visible plugin for checking if it is visible or not) in JQuery.

But it doesn't seem to work.

On the other hand in the second example given below, I have done everything just the same way except that instead of the `animate()` function I have used the `$(".scroll-header").css("height", "70px")`, and it works perfectly.

**But I need the animation. How do I solve this?**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 console.log("script.js is detected");//check
 
 
 
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  console.log("window onscroll being called.");//check
  if ( $("div.view").visible(true) ) {
   console.log("YES if ( $(\"div.view\").visible(true) )");//check
   $(".scroll-header").animate({"height": "0px"}, 350);
  } else {
   console.log("NO if ( $(\"div.view\").visible(true) )");//check
   $(".scroll-header").animate({"height": "70px"}, 350);
  }
 });
 
});
```

```css
.view {
 height:500px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:crimson;
}

.second {
 height:2500px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:purple;
}

.scroll-header {
 background-color:yellow;
 width:100%;
 height:0px;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 position:fixed;
}
.header {
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 background-color:cyan;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
}




* {
 border:0px;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.visible/1.1.0/jquery.visible.min.js"></script>

<div class="view">.</div>
 <div class="header">.</div>
 <div class="scroll-header">.</div>
 <div class="second">.</div>
```

OR [**JSFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldj4hftr/1/)

***SSCCE without Animation:***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 console.log("script.js is detected");//check
 
 
 
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  console.log("window onscroll being called.");//check
  if ( $("div.view").visible(true) ) {
   console.log("YES if ( $(\"div.view\").visible(true) )");//check
   //$(".scroll-header").animate({"height": "0px"}, 350);
          $(".scroll-header").css("height", "0px");
  } else {
   console.log("NO if ( $(\"div.view\").visible(true) )");//check
   //$(".scroll-header").animate({"height": "70px"}, 350);
   $(".scroll-header").css("height", "70px");
  }
 });
 
});
```

```css
.view {
 height:500px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:crimson;
}

.second {
 height:2500px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:purple;
}

.scroll-header {
 background-color:yellow;
 width:100%;
 height:0px;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 position:fixed;
}
.header {
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 background-color:cyan;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
}




* {
 border:0px;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.visible/1.1.0/jquery.visible.min.js"></script>
<div class="view">.</div>
<div class="header">.</div>
<div class="scroll-header">.</div>
<div class="second">.</div>
```

OR [**JSFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bfp08nbw/).

Comment: You have **syntax error** in your `js` of first fiddle.. Here is the **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/Ldj4hftr/2/)** which works perfectly...

Comment: Reduce the animation time also. http://jsfiddle.net/Ldj4hftr/3/

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Doesn't work at all. The yellow colored `.scroll-header` doesn't show at all.

Comment: @SujataChanda It is taking ridiculously long to _start_ appearing. I have to scroll down and then sat and waited, and then after a few seconds it appeared.

Comment: Here is the **[new updated one](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/Ldj4hftr/5/)**

Comment: Yes that is why I told you to reduce the animation time.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Why did you change `visible(true)` to `visible()`? I am using jquery-visible plugin. [See the syntax here.](https://www.customd.com/articles/13/checking-if-an-element-is-visible-on-screen-using-jquery). This change changed the logic of my program: with `visible()`, it checks if _the entire_ element is on the screen, and with `visible(true)` it checks if _any part of_ the element is visible on screen.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao You can see `visible(true)` working in the second SSCCE in the question. Because of the change you made, the yellow bar appears as soon as the document is loaded.